# generator-angular: task "karma" not found when calling `grunt test`

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner

I'm trying to setup a development environment with Yeoman for AngularJS,
I installed Yeoman according to the instructions: `sudo npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli generator-angular` and I'm generating a new app with `yo angular`.

After the app is generated, running `karma start` does start the karma server, but running `grunt test` result in

```
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: object is not a function
Warning: Task "karma" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

how do I fix this ?

EDIT: some files (generated fresh from Yeoman)

Gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
  return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // load all grunt tasks
  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  // configurable paths
  var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  try {
    yeomanConfig.app = require('./component.json').appPath || yeomanConfig.app;
  } catch (e) {}

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    watch: {
      coffee: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:dist']
      },
      coffeeTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:test']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ],
        tasks: ['livereload']
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              lrSnippet,
              mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
              mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
              mountFolder(connect, 'test')
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },
    coffee: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
          src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components',
        relativeAssets: true
      },
      dist: {},
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },
    concat: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
            '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }
    },
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
          //collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          useShortDoctype: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true*/
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'components/**/*',
            'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
            'styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.renameTask('regarde', 'watch');

  grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee:dist',
    'compass:server',
    'livereload-start',
    'connect:livereload',
    'open',
    'watch'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee',
    'compass',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'coffee',
    'compass:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'imagemin',
    'cssmin',
    'htmlmin',
    'concat',
    'copy',
    'cdnify',
    'ngmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
};
```

karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath = '';

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
];

// list of files to exclude
exclude = [];

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: dots || progress || growl
reporters = ['progress'];

// web server port
port = 8080;

// cli runner port
runnerPort = 9100;

// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors = true;

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel = LOG_INFO;

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch = false;

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers = ['Chrome'];

// If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
captureTimeout = 5000;

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun = false;
```

test/spec/controllers/main.js:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('testApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });
});'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('testApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share your Gruntfile, test file, and anything else relevant?

Comment: I added Grunfile.js, karma.conf.js and a test example to the question, those are all generated fresh from the Yeoman generator

Comment: @GalBen-Haim which version of Node/npm are you running? I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading my Node version. Check out my answer for details.

Answer (score 88):

```
npm install grunt-karma --save-dev
```

or if you need it

```
sudo npm install grunt-karma --save-dev
```

from the docs on https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-karma

Comment: Also i have had to install karma-phantomjs-launcher  and karma-jasmine:  npm install grunt-karma  karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-jasmine --save-dev

Comment: This is what I had to add: `npm install grunt-karma karma karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-jasmine jasmine-core phantomjs --save-dev`

Answer (score 17):

after running

```
npm install grunt-karma --save-dev
```

add the following line to Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
```

this works for me.

Comment: Shouldn't the angular generator be fixed to include this in the package.json?

Comment: You wouldn't need to add the `loadNpmTasks` command, since you've put it into package.json and Gruntfile.js calls `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);`

Answer (score 5):

The obvious answers already posted here were completely unhelpful to me. If reinstalling grunt-karma via npm didn't work, and explicitly loading the task in the Gruntfile didn't help, you may be running a version of npm prior to 1.2.10.

It turns out that recent versions of grunt-karma rely on [peer dependencies](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/), which were introduced to Node with version 8.19. After upgrading Nodejs (which also installs npm) and upgrading karma globally, I discovered I needed to edit my karma config files as well. You'll want to add `frameworks: ['jasmine'],` to `karma.conf.js` and remove references to `JASMINE` and `JASMINE_ADAPTER` from the `files` setting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It took me some banging my head against the wall, your answer saved the day for the wall

Answer (score 1):

A was having the problem of Not Found.

Finally I realize it was a problem with the port (8080 was already used)

in karma.config.js change the port number:

```
// web server port
port: 9999,
```