# Cannot install phantomJS in Karma

Tags: phantomjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

```
WARN [config]: config.configure() is deprecated, please use config.set() instead.
WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-phantomjs".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-phantomjs --save-dev
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9018/
WARN [launcher]: Can not load "PhantomJS", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

Getting this error. When running npm install karma-phantomjs --save-dev I get an error.

```
npm ERR! 404 'karma-phantomjs' is not in the npm registry.
```

I installed karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev   but i still get an error when running grunt watch.

Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: @karma-phantomjs@ simply does not exist in the npm-registry, whats the error you are getting with @karma-phantomjs-launcher@? showing your gruntfile would also help...

Comment: Ive added my Gruntfile here: http://pastebin.com/gzmcRSKF

karma-phantomjs-launcher installed perfectly fine. I get no error. However when I run grunt watch, I still get the error regarding phantomJS.

When running phantomjs --version I get a return of 1.9.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I realized that I needed to run:

```
npm install -g karma@canary phantomjs karma-phantomjs-launcher
```

Once I ran that I went back into my karma-unit.tpl.js file and instead of karma-phantomjs, I changed this to karma-phantomjs-launcher.

Now when I execute a command like grunt build, I get no error regarding phantomJS

Answer (score 79):

`npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev`

`npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev`

Then add the following line to karma.config.js

`plugins : ['karma-jasmine', 'karma-phantomjs-launcher']`

Comment: sudo npm install grunt-karma --save-dev (if not installed);see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313157/generator-angular-task-karma-not-found-when-calling-grunt-test/17875685#17875685

Comment: @MartyLavender this should probably be the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 16):

I got tripped up by this today running

- karma: 0.13.7
- karma-phantomjs-launcher: 1.0.0

What isn't very obvious is that the launcher has a dependency on:

- phantomjs-prebuilt

So if you, install this locally everything should run fine, eg:

`npm install phantomjs-prebuilt --save-dev`

Comment: it solved my issue. strange that this dependancy is not installed together with launcher module

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue still open on the repo: [#31](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/31)

Strangely enough the following worked for my Debian based system:

```
apt-get install libfontconfig
```

How did I get into this? Reading a [comment](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/31#issuecomment-49564925) from the ticket. Hope this will help for others too :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm running in a CentOS 7 Docker container. Had similar issue.

Had to:

```
yum install -y tar bzip2 freetype fontconfig
```

Then

```
npm install phantomjs --save-dev
```

worked without errors, which allowed

```
npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

and that allowed

```
gulp test
```

to run without Karma or PhantomJS errors.

Comment: should that second-to-last command be `npm install karma-phantom-js-launcher --save-dev`?

Comment: @meatspace Thanks, fixed it, but you had extra "-" in yours:)

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same. I deleted all the temporary directories and, after rerun it worked.
Before that i also reinstalled phantomjs but without success. It's possible that this influenced, anyway (but i think deleting the temporary directories did the job). Anyway, after deleting temporary folders you can try, if it didn't work you can reinstall phantomjs and also other stuff as other users already wrote.